# Pandas data frame. Change float format. Keep type "float"

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, rounding, precision

I'm trying to change a format of pd data frame column without changing the type of data.
Here is what I have: `df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [24.0, 32.0}])`

I'd like to represent Age in `24 32`  type or `24.00 32.00` and keep them as floats.
Here is what I can do:

```
df['Age'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

But this line changes the type of data to object. 
I was also trying to apply: `

```
df = df.style.format({'Age': '{:,.2f}'.format})`
```

but there is something wrong in it. Please help to figure out the right way.

Comment: I'm asking for both ways: 0.00 and without decimals at all, but keeping float type.

Comment: if i'm not mistaken format is a string method. try to use round method with the number of digits after the dot. i.e round(age,2) or round(age,0)

Comment: So, when you do `df.Age` it must be a float itself.

Comment: @LiorT, thanks, I try df.Age.round(2), but there is again something wrong I do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your dataFrame itself a type float.

Dataframe:

```
>>> df
    Age
0  24.0
1  32.0
```

Check DataFrame type:

```
>>> df.dtypes
Age    float64
dtype: object
```

check dtype for DataFrame column type:

```
>>> df.Age
0    24.0
1    32.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

OR even check like:

```
>>> df['Age'].dtype.kind
'f'
```

The way you are using to round up double digit zeros that's correct but converting them again to float will get them remain in single zero as being float.

```
>>> df['Age'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
0    24.00
1    32.00
Name: Age, dtype: object
```

---

As you are interested keeping either mimic like int values `24, 32` or `24.00 & 32.00`, if you are only interested in the display of floats then you can do `pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:.0f}'.format)`, which doesn't actually affect your data.

### For Floating Format without leading zeros

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:.0f}'.format)
>>> df
   Age
0   24
1   32

>>> df.dtypes
Age    float64
dtype: object
```

### For Floating Format

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format','{:.2f}'.format)
>>> df
    Age
0 24.00
1 32.00
>>> df.dtypes
Age    float64
dtype: object
```

## Alternative way

Set the display precision option:

```
>>> pd.set_option('precision', 0)
>>> df
   Age
0   24
1   32

>>> df.dtypes
Age    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to keep these floats in .2f or .0f format as floats?

Comment: @Jerry, see the updated answer ,, hope that will help.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using df.round is the best way:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [24.0, 32.0]})
>>> df2 = df.round({'Ages': 2})
>>> print(df2.dtypes)
>>> df2
    Age
0   24.00
1   32.00
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply to specific column of the dataframe

```
df["col_name"] = df["col_name"].apply(lambda x: format(float(x),".2f"))
```